# How to make a label value not searchable in a Repeater?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptListaRequisicoes" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="example3" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:200px">Nome</th>
                                <th style="width:50px">Pedido</th>
                                <th style="width:50px">Estado</th>
                                <th style="width:50px"></th>
                                <th style="width:50px"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:200px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblIdReq" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdReq") %>' Style="display: none;" />
                            <asp:LinkButton Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ID="lkbtnDetalhes" OnClick="DetalhesRequisicao"><%# Eval("Nome") %> </asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50px">
                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblPedido" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TipoPedido") %>'/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50px">
                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblEstado" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descricao") %>'/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50px">
                            <asp:LinkButton Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ID="OnAprovar" Text="Aprovar" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Nome","Javascript:return confirm(\"Deseja aprovar a requisição: {0}\");") %>' OnClick="OnAprovar_clik"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50px">
                            <asp:LinkButton Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ID="OnRecusar" Text="Recusar" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Nome","Javascript:return confirm(\"Deseja recusar a requisição: {0}\");") %>' OnClick="OnRecusar_clik"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>


<script>
     $(function () {
            $('#example1').DataTable()
            $('#example3').DataTable()
            $('#example4').DataTable({
                'paging': true,
                'lengthChange': false,
                'searching': false,
                'ordering': true,
                'info': true,
                'autoWidth': false
            })
        })
</script>
```

This is a simple table in repeater using DataTable style.

The table has a searchbox and If I type a number it will show me the ID linked to that record. How can i disable it being serached like I disabled it being shown? I tried to disable the label but that didn't work either so I really don't see what else i can try to make this controller not searchable

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a class to your labels (i.e. using `CssClass="SomeClassName"` on your asp:Label elements) and refine your search to exclude elements with that class.

If your search is using jQuery (based on the tags), you could use the `:not("SomeClassName")` on your jQuery selector to exclude those elements.

Comment: I'm not really sure how can I access the search bar settings and do this since it's all set on the script in DataTable properties

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem, I solved it with this code

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "searchable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

the number in front of target is the column. It was working for me because I had the ID label on same  as the Name, so i just created another  to place the ID label and problem solved